# Как преобразовать текст во время использую формулы google sheets?

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Можно ли преобразовать текст во время использую формулы google sheets?

ячейки содержат время в форматах:

**1210** *(должно пониматься как **12:10**)*

**192220** *(должно пониматься как **19:22:20**)*

**81015** *(должно пониматься  как **8:10:15**)*

Comment: Стандартными средствами гугл таблиц, я понимаю, что нельзя.

Comment: я сообразил что можно

Comment: я сообразил что можно '=TIME(value(MID(<<ячейка со временем>>;<<начинаем с символа Х>>;2));value(MID(<<ячейка со временем>>;<<начинаем с символа Y>>;2));value(mid(<<ячейка со временем>>;<<начинаем с символа Z>>;2)))' - это работает если количество символов обозначающих время 6, но как сделать если запись сокращенная - не могу сообразить